# how can i show the glyphicon in js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I used a glyphicon but i made the visibilty:hidden in CSS , i want  when the user write something and click on the button (post) the glyphicon (#gl1) will show , but i have a problem , when i do it by js the glypicon does not show , i don't know why

My Code:
My CSS :

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial-scale=1">     
    <title>POST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <style>
    div{
    background-color: beige;
    height:400px;
    width:500px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 3px solid brown;
    margin:20px;    
    }
    div #txtar{
    width:470px;
    height:280px;
    font-size:30px;
    padding-left: 13px;
    resize: none;    
    }
    div .btn{
    float: right;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-right:9px;
    width:80px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size:17px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:beige; 
    border:1px solid brown;    
    }
    #post{
    width:470px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid brown;

       }
    #post .glyphicon-pencil , .glyphicon-trash{
    float: right;
    color:brown;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    visibility: hidden;
        }
    #post #gl1{
     float: right;
     color:brown;
     font-size: 20px;
     margin-left: 10px;
     visibility:visible;   
      }   
    #post span{
     border:1px solid brown;
     padding:10px;   
    }   
    </style>   
    </head>
```

And this is the HTML Elements i want when the user click on the button "post" which has id="post"
, the glypicon will show ...

```
    <body>
    <div>
    <textarea id="txtar" placeholder="Write Something ..."></textarea>    
    <button class="btn" onclick="ClickPost();">Post</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="">Cancel</button>    
    </div>    
    <div id="post" onmousedown="">    
    <span id="gl1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" ></span><br>    
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" id="gl2"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" id="gl3"></span>   
    </div>
```

JS Code :

```
    <script>
    function ClickPost(){
    var txt= window.txtar.value;
    var txt2;    
    window.post.innerHTML=txt;
    window.txtar.value=" ";     
    if (!txt){
    txt2 = txt;  
    window.post.innerHTML="Please write something ..!";
    window.post.style.color="#a80707";
 
    }
    else{
    window.gl1.style.visibility="visible";    
    }   
     }   

    </script>
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
    </body>    
    </html>
```

and when i open the console i find this message:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
at ClickPost (Post edit and delete.html:94)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Post edit and delete.html:67)

please can any one help

Answer (score 0):

This command `window.post.innerHTML = txt;` will replace the contents of `div#post` element with new `txt` value, so all the other elements inside this `div#post` will be erased (and so the 3 spans).

To protect spans you can add another inner element into the `div#post` for example like this:

```html
<div id="post" onmousedown="">    
    <span id="gl1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" ></span><br>    
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" id="gl2"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" id="gl3"></span>   
    <span id="postContents"></span> <!-- here it is -->
</div>
```

```js
function ClickPost() {
  var txt = window.txtar.value;
  window.postContents.innerHTML = txt;
  window.txtar.value = "";
  if (!txt) {
    window.postContents.innerHTML = "Please write something ..!";
    window.post.style.color = "#a80707";
  } else {
    window.gl1.style.visibility = "visible";
    window.post.style.color = "";
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: beige;
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid brown;
  margin: 20px;
}

div #txtar {
  width: 470px;
  height: 280px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 13px;
  resize: none;
}

div .btn {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 9px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: beige;
  border: 1px solid brown;
}

#post {
  width: 470px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid brown;
}

#post .glyphicon-pencil,
.glyphicon-trash {
  float: right;
  color: brown;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#gl1 {
  float: right;
  color: brown;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#gl1, #gl3 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#post span {
  border: 1px solid brown;
  padding: 10px;
}

#post #postContents {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <textarea id="txtar" placeholder="Write Something ..."></textarea>
  <button class="btn" onclick="ClickPost();">Post</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="">Cancel</button>
</div>
<div id="post" onmousedown="">
  <span id="gl1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span><br>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" id="gl2"></span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" id="gl3"></span>
  <span id="postContents"></span>
</div>
```

Note: I've slightly edited your CSS, HTML and JS, keeping maximum of your code.

P.S. If you have questions, just ask.